# Category of modules over commutative monoid is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

I am interested in proving the following statement:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a tensor category. Then the category of modules over a commutative monoid $A$ in $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ is abelian and symmetric monoidal, and every such module is the quotient of a flat module.

Here by 'tensor category' I mean a $k$-linear abelian and rigid symmetric monoidal category whose tensor product is $k$-bilinear and exact in both variables. An $A$-module $M$ is flat if the funtor $-\otimes_A M$ is exact.

I am able to show that this category is symmetric monoidal, but I am having some trouble showing that it is abelian and that every module is the quotient of a flat one. What I found out so far:

- The zero object of $\mathcal{A}$ also is a zero object in $A\textbf{Mod}$ together with the trivial action
- As biproduct of $(M,\rho_M)$ and $(N,\rho_N)$ one can just take the biproduct $M\oplus N$ in $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ with the action $\rho_M \oplus \rho_N$
- I think the following diagrams make the kernel and cokernel of a morphism of $A$-modules (taken in $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$) into $A$-modules, hence showing that $A\textbf{Mod}$ has all kernels and cokernels (I think $A\otimes \text{coker} f = \text{coker}(\text{id}\otimes f)$):

[image]

I have no idea how to show that every monomorphism is a kernel and every epimorphism is a cokernel in $A\textbf{Mod}$. Also, I do not know how to go about that property with the flatness. I think this is a quite common statement, and yet I could not find a proof anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Question has been answered on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395859/category-of-modules-over-internal-monoid-is-abelian